# GLSL vertex shader to keep screenspace size

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have the following geometry made up of 6 vertices:

[image]

Now I want that a, b and c keep their lengths in screenspace. d should just behave as normal (grow / shrink in screenspace along with "camera zoom").

Is the vertex shader, to adjust the position of the vertices to get that kind of behavior, the right way to go? What would be an efficient way to do that? Would I use `gl_VertexID` to adjust the different vertices in the shader?

Comment: why would your like to use shader for this,  applying  a transformation matrix would do the trick, if I understood your requirement correctly

Comment: how would b stay the same length in screenspace and d not, using a transform?

Comment: do you want to stretch d ?

Comment: do you need to draw something on the "frame"? if not, you can use only 3 vertices to draw these two *fixed width* lines by setting line width to b/c via `glLineWidth()`.

Comment: then adjust the position of one vertex is enough.

Comment: I already looked at glLines, but I need more flexibility and can't make use of them unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by providing relative offsets in screen space for each vertex as a separate attribute to the vertex shader. You can then apply the transformation to the coordinates without the offset, and add the offset to the transformed coordinates.

In fact, you might be able to pack these offsets into the existing position attribute, as long as the total number of components does not exceed four. For example, if your positions only have two components, you could pack a two component offset into the same attribute.

To illustrate the idea, I'll pick the case where your positions have two coordinates in `x` and `y`.  We now store only the coordinates of the point you want to transform in `x` and `y`, and the screen space offset in `w` and `z`. For the given shape, with the origin in the bottom-left corner, the 6 vertices then are:

```
(0, 0, a - c, 0 )
(0, 0, a    , 0 )
(0, d, a    , 0 )
(0, d, 0    , 0 )
(0, d, 0    , -b)
(0, d, a - c, -b)
```

Note how x/y and z/w add up to the vertex coordinates. But since you only want to transform `d`, only that dimension is part of x/y, which we will apply the transformation to. All dimensions involving `b`, `c` and `d` are in w/z, which we will apply untransformed.

Then, in the vertex shader, the key pieces could look like this:

```
in vec4 Pos;
uniform mat4 Transf;
...
vec4 transfPos = Transf * vec4(Pos.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
transfPos.xy += Pos.wz;
```

As indicated before, we transform the x/y components of the input vertex, and add the w/z components to the transformed position.

You may have to tweak this to do exactly what you need. For example, it gets a little trickier if you have a project transformation. But the basic idea of feeding a separate screen space offset into the vertex shader should still work.